# Creating high quality gif with imagemagick causes white specks

Tags: imagemagick, gif

I want to create a gif from the following images: (I don't have enough reputation to embed them)

```
https://github.com/Dragon8oy/argon-grub-theme/raw/master/docs/Crystals.png
https://github.com/Dragon8oy/argon-grub-theme/raw/master/docs/Grey.png
https://github.com/Dragon8oy/argon-grub-theme/raw/master/docs/Night.png
```

I'm using:

```
convert -alpha remove -layers OptimizePlus -delay 150 -loop 0 *.png Gallery.gif
```

Which creates the result:

```
https://i.imgur.com/lgHskVq.gif
```

The result has white specs over the middle mountain in the 3rd frame.
I'm not worried about filesize, so if a lossless gif is an option, that'll work.
Thanks :)

Comment: What is your IM version and platform? The result looks fine to me. Your Night.png file has white spots over the mountains in the input image. So they will show in the output gif.

Comment: I'm on Debian Sid, IM version: 6.9.11.24. Night.png has white dots in it, but not on any of the mountains, and the middle mountain is covered in white dots not present on Night.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick quantization by default uses dithering. Your Night.png image has more than 256 colors and GIF only allows 256. So when quantized to 256 colors the spots get created from the dithering. You can disable the dithering and get a smoother result by adding +dither to your command. This works for me on IM 6.9.11.34 Q16 Mac OSX.

```
convert -delay 150 Crystals.png Grey.png Night.png +dither -alpha off -loop 0 Gallery.gif
```

[image]